# Trying to display total inventory method in GUI

Tags: java, swing, awt

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.*;

class Book implements Comparable<Book> {

    protected long isbn;
    protected String title;
    protected String autName;
    protected int year;
    protected String pubName;
    protected double price;
    protected int quantity;

    // Constructor
    public Book(long isbn, String title, String autName, int year, String pubName, double price) {
        setIsbn(isbn);
        setTitle(title);
        setAut(autName);
        setYear(year);
        setPub(pubName);
        setPrice(price);
    }

    // methods for class variables
    public long getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(long isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAut() {
        return autName;
    }

    public void setAut(String autName) {
        this.autName = autName;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getPub() {
        return pubName;
    }

    public void setPub(String pubName) {
        this.pubName = pubName;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    //toString for the book array
    public String toString() {
        return "ISBM: " + isbn + "\n" + "Title: " + title + "\n" + "Author's Name: " + autName + "\n" + "Year Published: " + year + "\n" + "Publisher's Name: " + pubName + "\n" + "Price: $" + price + "\n\n";
    }

    //comparable for array
    public int compareTo(Book otherBook) {
        return title.compareTo(otherBook.getTitle());
    }
}// end class Book
```

---

```
class EBook extends Book implements Comparable<Book> {

    private String website;

    //constructor and super
    public EBook(long isbn, String title, String autName, int year,
            String pubName, double price, String website) {
        super(isbn, title, autName, year, pubName, price);

        setWebsite(website);
    }

    // get and set 
    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }

    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }

    public double discount() {
        return price * 0.10;
    }

    DecimalFormat money = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");

    //toString for the Book array
    public String toString() {
        return "ISBM: " + isbn + "\n"
                + "Title: " + title + "\n"
                + "Author's Name: " + autName + "\n"
                + "Year Published: " + year + "\n"
                + "Publisher's Name: " + pubName + "\n"
                + "Price: " + money.format(price) + "\n"
                + "Website: " + website + "\n"
                + "Discount: " + money.format(discount()) + "\n\n";
    }

    //comparable for array
    public int compareTo(Book otherBook) {
        return title.compareTo(otherBook.getTitle());
    }
}//end class EBook
```

---

```
public class BookStore {

    //total price of inventory method
    public static double calculateInventoryTotal(Book[] books) {
        double total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
            total += books[i].getPrice();
        }

        return total;
    }
    static int bookIndex = 0;

    public static JTextArea prepareDisplay(Book myBook, JTextArea myTextArea) {

        DecimalFormat money = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
        myTextArea.setText("");
        myTextArea.append("Book Store Inventory: \n\n");
        myTextArea.append(myBook.toString());
        myTextArea.append("Total Inventory Value: ");
        return myTextArea;
    }
    //main method

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // book array
        final Book[] inventory = new Book[5];

        Book a = new Book(7423540089L, "No David!", "David Shannon", 2009, "Shannon Rock", 12.99);
        EBook b = new EBook(75260012L, "David goes to School", "David Shannon", 2010, "Shannon Rock", 11.98, "http://www.tinyurl.qqwert67o9");
        Book c = new Book(743200616L, "Simple Abundance", "Sarah Breathnach", 2009, "Scribner", 14.99);
        EBook d = new EBook(78137521819L, "The very hungry caterpillar", "Eric Carle", 2005, "Philomel Books", 13.99, "http://www.tinyurl.fguopt8u90");
        Book e = new Book(9781416987116L, "We're going on a bear hunt", "Michael Rosen", 2009, "McElderry", 15.99);

        inventory[0] = a;
        inventory[1] = b;
        inventory[2] = c;
        inventory[3] = d;
        inventory[4] = e;
        Arrays.sort(inventory);

        //parameters of the JTextArea
        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(15, 15);
        textArea.setText("");
        textArea.setEditable(false);

        DecimalFormat money = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

        JButton firstButton = new JButton("First");
        buttonPanel.add(firstButton);
        firstButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                bookIndex = 0;
                prepareDisplay(inventory[bookIndex], textArea);
            }
        });

        JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
        buttonPanel.add(nextButton);
        nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                bookIndex++;
                if (bookIndex >= inventory.length) {
                    bookIndex = 0;
                }
                prepareDisplay(inventory[bookIndex], textArea);
            }
        });

        JButton previousButton = new JButton("Previous");
        buttonPanel.add(previousButton);
        previousButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                bookIndex--;
                if (bookIndex < 0) {
                    bookIndex = inventory.length - 1;
                }
                prepareDisplay(inventory[bookIndex], textArea);
            }
        });

        JButton lastButton = new JButton("Last");
        buttonPanel.add(lastButton);
        lastButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                bookIndex = (inventory.length - 1);
                prepareDisplay(inventory[bookIndex], textArea);
            }
        });

        JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("bluehills.jpg"));
        JPanel logoPanel = new JPanel();
        logoPanel.add(logoLabel);

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(centerPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        centerPanel.add(prepareDisplay(inventory[bookIndex], textArea)); //show the first employee

        //calculate inventory total
        double inventoryTotal = calculateInventoryTotal(inventory);

        //myTextArea.append("Total Inventory Value: " + money.format(inventoryTotal) + "\n\n");

        //set the GUI window with the parameters
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Book Store Program");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // set layout
        frame.add(logoPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH); //add logo
        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH); // add previous and next button to frame
        frame.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); // add center panel to frame
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}// end class
```

I am trying to display the total inventory value in the GUI after the total inventory string using the calculateInventoryTotal method. I cannot get it to display properly so I am asking for help. I search for hours but cannot find an answer to this question. Thank you in advance for helping me complete this project.

Comment: You state that `"I cannot get it to display properly..."` but haven't told us what's wrong with your current display or how you're trying to display it. Please provide more salient details. Also, if you are trying to display multiple Book objects at once, a very common way to do so is to use a JTable. Are you trying this?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCTRE).

Comment: Can you explain what supposed to appear and when?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get the `inventoryTotal` value using this statement

```
double inventoryTotal = calculateInventoryTotal(inventory);
```

but you never assgin that value to a gui element for displaying

Comment: There is no variable named `myTextArea` that is in scope at that point in the code. There is, however, one named `textArea` but that might not solve OP's problem.

Comment: Trying to get the total inventory to display after the string in the code block prepareDisplay.

Comment: I was able to fix it sorry for the confusion. I needed the total inventory value for all the book in money format to appear after "Total Inventory Value: "